# How do I use Wordpress PHP functions in my Javascript code?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, jquery, javascript

Let's say I want to run the javascript function `launchMyPlugin()` only on post detail pages. At first, I was doing something like this:

**myPlugin.js**

```
if ( is_single() ) {
    launchMyPlugin();
}
```

However, this obviously does not work since `is_single()` is a php function. What is the right way to do this then? Do I need to add the condition to my .php file instead? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check is_single before enqueue the js file

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', '_enqueue');

function _enqueue(){
   if(is_single(){
       wp_enqueue_script(......);
   }
}
```